# Angular 2/4 How to determine the origin of event propagated by a child directive within nested attribute directives?

Tags: html, angular, dom, attributes, angular-directive

I have an issue in dealing with a hover event that is being propagated from a child of nested elements that are of the same directive. I am pretty new to Angular, so please be gentle and bear with me if I am missing something obvious.

### What I am trying to accomplish:

I have a custom attribute directive that I am writing to create a pseudo-venn diagram ui module in which a circle will expand when hovered over. The idea is that I am trying to achieve this using a single custom directive, with behaviours changing depending on the location of the element within the dom, where if the parent of an element with the directive tag is not another element with the directive tag then it is viewed as a "root circle", otherwise if the element with the tag has a parent with the directive tag then it is viewed as a "child circle" as shown below.

```
      <div vennCircle diameter="20vh" percentOverlap="35" parentAngle="300" id="smc">
        Parent
        <div vennCircle diameter="30vh" percentOverlap="35" parentAngle="0" id="smc1">
          child 1
        </div>
        <div vennCircle diameter="30vh" percentOverlap="35" parentAngle="90" id="smc2">
          child 2
        </div>
      </div>
```

I followed the [Angular Docs for finding a parent component through injecting](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#find-a-parent-component-by-injection) in order to create the directive as shown below and have been able to use this in order to successfully distinguish the parent from the child directive element.

```
export abstract class Parent { name: string; }

@Directive({
  selector: '[vennCircle]',
  providers: [{ provide: Parent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => VennDiagramDirective) }]
})
export class VennDiagramDirective implements AfterViewInit, Parent {
  name: string

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, @SkipSelf() @Optional() public parent: Parent) {
    console.log(el);
    console.log(parent);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event']) onMouseEnter(event: any) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,255,1)';
  }
}
```

Following are the Angular docs for creating a custom attribute directive (I am limited in number of links that I can post) I am trying to capture the hover event to trigger other behavior in the code above, it is simply changing the background color of the element hovered over.

---

### My problem:

The issue that I am having is that if I hover over just the parent circle, everything works as expected and the background color changes, however if I hover over either of the two child circles, they will also change the color, but so will the parent circle since the event propagates, the following images demonstrate what it looks like:

[link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL0YG.png)

Now I may be new to Angular, but this behaviour alone does not surprise me, it is my understanding that events propagate or bubble up and I was under the impression that this was supposed to occur first at the lowest level and moving upward in the hierarchy. If my understanding is correct, then it should follow that the hover event should be received by the child circle directive first when the child is hovered over and then should propagate upwards in the tree to the parent circle. If that follows, then I should be able to stop propagation of the event when it is first received, resulting in only the child circle changing colors, however this is not the case.

When I printed to the console with a timestamp, it shows that the parent circle ("#smc") is receiving the event prior to its child ("#smc1"), as shown below:

```
ElementRef {nativeElement: div#smc}
1504205896178
ElementRef {nativeElement: div#smc1}
1504205896206
```

---

### My question(s)

- How, if possible, can I prevent the parent element directive from receiving the hover event of its child?
- If the above is not possible, how can I determine the origin of the hover event such that I can filter out events that originated from the child elements in the parent element directive?

---

### Notes

- I am currently dead set on achieving this with a single directive, even if it is tricky, the idea being that I want to be able to use this ui module elsewhere or share it with others, in a way that only requires a single declaration/import in the module.ts. I am already aware that I could create X different components/directives for each type of circle, however I do not want that, that makes using the module too complex in my opinion.
- I do not want a dev using this to have to manually setup the events in the html, an attribute directive enables this so I want to be able to use it.

Thank you all in advance for your help, please comment if you need more info, or if I did something wrong, remember that I am new and learning!

Comment: AFAIK `mouseevent` is not bubbling. `mouseover` is bubbling

Comment: @yurzui I am not certain what you are trying to say, the only event being listened for in the code I posted is "mouseenter", could you please elaborate?

Comment: @yurzui After reading more documentation on the two event types you mentioned, your comment answered my question. Mouseenter, what I was using above, is not in fact bubbling, and therefore triggers on all levels of the dom hierarchy, which in my case resulted in what seemed like bubbling in reverse. Mouseover, on the other hand, is bubbling and begins at the lowest level of the dom hierarchy, and can be intercepted and stopped. Feel free to write it up as an answer if you'd like the points/whatever, otherwise I will write the answer in a day or so. Thanks!